# Rewrite Ports for Google Compute Instance Based on Subdomains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, portforwarding, nat

I want to be able to connect to a compute instance via something like this:
*sub1.domain.com:443* and
*sub2.domain.com:443*
and the ports should be rewritten to *domain.com:6001* and *domain.com:6002*, so that the compute instance just gets the traffic with the changed port.

How would I do that? As far as I know Cloud NAT cannot redirect incoming ports.

Comment: You would need to use a load balancer or proxy to rewrite URLs which is a Layer 7 feature (HTTP). I am not aware of another service that provides port remapping.

Comment: Cloud NAT will allow your instances without a public IP address to reach the Internet and won't be useful for this use case, if you are using Apache you could try mod_proxy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html, have you tried it?